# How do I distinguish between when user is root vs when user is sudo'd

Tags: c++, qt, root, sudo, kde-plasma

I'd like to write some Qt code for a KDE app that distinguishes between when a user is root vs when the user has used sudo to request elevated privileges, so the app can display a different message for each use case. Checking for `uid == 0` captures both cases, but how do I distinguish between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read `SUDO_USER` environment variable using [`QProcessEnvironment` class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocessenvironment.html):

```
QProcessEnvironment system_env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
qDebug() << "USER  : " << system_env.value("USER");
qDebug() << "SUDOER: " << system_env.value("SUDO_USER");
```

or `#include <unistd.h>` and use [`getlogin`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getlogin.3.html):

```
std::cout << "LOGGED IN USER: " << getlogin() << std::endl;
```